# How to log JavaScript client stack traces in AWS CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, sentry

It would be nice to consolidate logging on AWS with our server logs - curiously tho I don’t see much chatter about the subject of using CloudWatch for logging client errors.